# How to configured spring session with EnableJdbcHttpSession?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-security, spring-session

I Managed to find an error (Bug) in 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session

Due to the fact that the project is poorly configured.

I set up that all sessions are saved in the database through the config: @EnableJdbcHttpSession  in Mysql (MariaDB).

The trouble is that the filter is one for all and any request to the front ... for example, give the statics (picture, css, etc.) - it has its own session key and also climbs into the database.

Everyone getting the picture.

Any request from the front in which there is a session and the cuckolds goes to the Mysql.
Requests that do not need to go to the database go there.

This is a large number of SELECT .... UPDATE ... table calls

SPRING_SESSION
SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES

How would this error be described to the developers?

[image]

**How to configured spring session with EnableJdbcHttpSession and filter ?
Only business request went to the database ?**

Comment: SessionId normally is a cookie. How about adding a filter with WrapRequest which modifies the cookie header suppressing the session id?

Comment: Yes, I think about HttpServletRequestWrapper ,  but is one and no good idea :(